# how to get custom error code through swagger annotation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, openapi-generator

```
*`I have below schema definition to represent commission amount in my openapi contract.`*


"properties": {
        "Amount": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "The amount of tnx",
          "pattern" : "^-?[0-9]*(\\.([0-9]{1,2}))?$",
          "format": "big-decimal",
          "minimum": 0.01,
          "maximum": 49999.99,
          "exclusiveMinimum": false,
          "exclusiveMaximum": false,
          "example" : "9999.99"
        },
```

**generated code:**

```
@NotNull @Valid @DecimalMin("0.01") @DecimalMax("49999.99") 
  @Schema(name = "amount", example = "9999.99", description = "The amount of tnx", required = true)
  public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }
```

*when i gave above 50000 or below 0.01 its given the right validation message through post man*

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "DecimalMax",
            "message": "must be less than or equal to 49999.99",
            "field": "Amount"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "DecimalMin",
            "message": "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
            "field": "Amount"
        }
    ]
}

but i want override the code with some some number to represent the error code like 100,101 etc

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "100",
            "message": "must be less than or equal to 49999.99",
            "field": "Amount"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "101",
            "message": "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
            "field": "Amount"
        }
    ]
}

can i specify any annotation on swagger to achieve this
```

Comment: which generator are you using?

Comment: openapitools.generator,  'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.0' //
generated swagger api and model
and  'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.2' generate swagger model.

Comment: no, `generatorName = ` what?  `java`? `spring`? There are a [lot of generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/scala-play-server) in the `openapi generator`

Comment: sorry for the delay, its generatorName = "spring" @tbatch

Answer (score 1):

By Default, when a field fails validation, Spring will throw a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.  This is managed internally by Springs `spring-boot-starter-validation`. You can override this exception handling using `@RestControllerAdvice` or `@ControllerAdvice`.

First, create a basic model for your response.  Here is an extremely simple one.

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class RestException {
  String code;
  String message;
}
```

Then, create your controller advice class.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    RestException exception = new RestException();
    exception.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
    var message = Optional.ofNullable(ex).map(MethodArgumentNotValidException::getBindingResult).map(BindingResult::getFieldError).orElse(null);

    exception.setMessage(Objects.isNull(message) ? "unidentified error" : message.getField() + " " + message.getDefaultMessage());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exception, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

this very simple example will return a response of

```
{
  "code": "400 BAD_REQUEST",
  "message": "amount must be greater than or equal to 0"
}
```

#### Note

You are free to set the code returned to the user as whatever you want (aka, exception.setCode("99999 MY_STATUS_CODE").  However, this will have no meaning to the user, as it won't match the headers sent by the controller as part of the `ResponseEntity`.  I recommend sticking with defined HttpStatus types as the code you display back to your users.

Also, unless you are specifically trying to get a `BigDecimal` as your type, setting the format of the number to `float` or `double` will result in the expected dataType.  Otherwise, declaring `big-decimal` isn't necessary, since that is the default for a `number` with no format defined.

Likewise, the defaults for `exclusiveMinimum` and `exclusiveMaximum` is false by default, so there is no need to include them in your schema.

Finally, I recommend adjusting your schema to include to response description.  Something along the lines of this

```yaml
responses:
  "200":
    description: OK
  "5XX":
    description: Unknown error has occurred
  "400":
    description: A required parameter is missing or an invalid datatype or value was provided for property.  
      Check the error message to check the invalid information, adjust the provided schema, and try again.
```

That should cover all of your bases.  Feel free to expand the `RestException` and `RestExceptionHandler` classes.  As I said, these are basic examples.  You can make them much more robust (i.e. multiple returns based upon the field or error message).